# Save array in Firestore and display it in the uitableview in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Swift and Firestore, where I have collection of tasks.

I populate each tableview cell with a task data. There is a field hashtags. Now it's just a string, but I want it to be an array of strings.
How can I save array of strings in Task model and correctly display it in the tableview?

My Task model file:

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore

protocol DocumentSerializable {
    init?(dictionary:[String:Any])
}

struct Task {
    var title: String
    var description: String
    var tip: String
    var hashtags: String

    var dictionary:[String:Any] {
        return [
            "title": title,
            "description": description,
            "tip": tip,
            "hashtags": hashtags
        ]
    }
}

extension Task : DocumentSerializable {

    init?(dictionary: [String : Any]) {

            let title = dictionary["title"] as? String ?? "Error! Title Field Not Found!"
            let description = dictionary["description"] as? String ?? "Error! Description Field Not Found!"
            let tip = dictionary["tip"] as? String ?? "Error! Tip Field Not Found!"
            let hashtags = dictionary["hashtags"] as? String ?? "Error! Hashtags Field Not Found!"

        self.init(title: title, description: description, tip: tip, hashtags: hashtags)
    }
}
```

My TableViewViewController file:

```
    import UIKit
    import Firebase
    import FirebaseAuth
    import FirebaseFirestore

    class TasksListScreen: UIViewController {

        var db = Firestore.firestore()
        var tasksArray = [Task]()

        @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            loadData()
    }

    // load data from the user tasks collection to the table view
    func loadData() {

        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
        let userTasksCollRef = db.collection("users").document(userID).collection("tasks")

        userTasksCollRef.getDocuments { (queryShapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error loading data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                self.tasksArray = queryShapshot!.documents.compactMap({Task(dictionary: $0.data())})

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension TasksListScreen: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tasksArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "taskCell") as! TaskViewCell

        let task = tasksArray[indexPath.row]

        cell.previewTitleLabel.text = task.title
        cell.previewMotivLabel.text = task.description
        cell.previewTipLabel.text = task.tip
        cell.previewHashtagsLabel.text = task.hashtags

        cell.cellDelegate = self
        cell.index = indexPath

        return cell
    }
    }
```

Comment: What is the issue you're facing?

Comment: Hello! I don't know how to correctly store hashtags field as an Array instead of a String in my Task model.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, You should modify the `hashtags` property in `Task` and the `init?(dictionary:)` method. Like this:

```
struct Task {
    var title: String
    var description: String
    var tip: String
    var hashtags: [String]

    var dictionary:[String: Any] {
        return [
            "title": title,
            "description": description,
            "tip": tip,
            "hashtags": hashtags
        ]
    }
}

extension Task: DocumentSerializable {

    init?(dictionary: [String : Any]) {

            let title = dictionary["title"] as? String ?? "Error! Title Field Not Found!"
            let description = dictionary["description"] as? String ?? "Error! Description Field Not Found!"
            let tip = dictionary["tip"] as? String ?? "Error! Tip Field Not Found!"
            let hashtags = dictionary["hashtags"] as? [String] ?? ["Error! Hashtags Field Not Found!"]

        self.init(title: title, description: description, tip: tip, hashtags: hashtags)
    }
}
```

Then you need to modify the cellForRow method's following line to pass the array and display it properly.

Modify this:

```
cell.previewHashtagsLabel.text = task.hashtags
```

To:

```
cell.handleHashTags(task.hashtags)
```

You need to add a new method in `TaskViewCell` class named `handleHashTags` and handle the array of strings `[String]` passed to display them.

Comment: Thank you! I've created a func handleHashtags(hashtags: [String]) { } . How can I implement it?

Comment: I figured everything out :) Thank you for your help once again!

Comment: I would advise against adding a method to a table view cell (especially if it's reusable) that parses data. You should parse all of your data before you render cells; asking the cell to parse data is a bad pattern. Do it before it gets to the data source, not in the data source, and especially not after in the cell.

Comment: @VeronikaBabii split the array into a string before the `cellForRowAt` method. Doing it in the cell is not a good idea.